# PHP DateTime format returns false for some timezones

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am trying to get current time for all  [PHP standard timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).
I am using below code to get current time for all timezones.

```
$dateTimeObj = new DateTime( "now", new DateTimeZone( $timezoneName ) );
return $dateTimeObj->format("D, g:i a");
```

$dateTimeObj->format() returns false when $timezoneName is one of the below

```
America/Metlakatla,
America/North_Dakota/Beulah,
America/Sitka,
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Works for me. PHP 5.4.11. What does this output: print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US')); ?

Comment: I am on PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5.  DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US')) to list timezones. This list includes America/Metlakatla,
America/North_Dakota/Beulah,
America/Sitka..

Comment: Strange. Just random idea: maybe you could try troubleshoot just by passing "D" to format(), then "g", etc. Also make sure you've got display_errors enabled and error_reporting set to E_ALL for troubleshooting. -- note that it works for me on my 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.7